# getParamertervalues() of HttpServletResponseWrapper is not getting invoke

Tags: java, rest

I am writing one request wrapper class to fix cross-site scripting issue. What i am facing problem is getParameterValues() method is not getting invoke when i call chain.dofilter(wrapperclass). Can anyone plz help me why thie method is not getting triggered?

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

    public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private static Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
            // Script fragments
            Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // src='...'
            Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // lonely script tags
            Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // eval(...)
            Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // expression(...)
            Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // javascript:...
            Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // vbscript:...
            Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // onload(...)=...
            Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL)
        };

        public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
            super(servletRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {
            String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);

            if (values == null) {
                return null;
            }

            int count = values.length;
            String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                encodedValues[i] = stripXSS(values[i]);
            }

            return encodedValues;
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(String parameter) {
            String value = super.getParameter(parameter);

            return stripXSS(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            String value = super.getHeader(name);
            return stripXSS(value);
        }

        private String stripXSS(String value) {
            if (value != null) {
                // NOTE: It's highly recommended to use the ESAPI library and uncomment the following line to
                // avoid encoded attacks.
                // value = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(value);

                // Avoid null characters
                value = value.replaceAll("\0", "");

                // Remove all sections that match a pattern
                for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns){
                    value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }



import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public final class XSSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        XSSRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
         chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet API provides multiple methods to pull parameters from a [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).  A particular [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) implementation can use any of these methods to pull parameters.  If you aren't seeing any invocations of [`ServletRequest#getParameterValues(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)), then it's likely that the underlying servlet that you filtered into simply isn't calling that method.  Perhaps it's calling the other methods.

For the sake of completion, I recommend that your request wrapper override all of these methods:

- [`ServletRequest#getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))
- [`ServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap())
- [`ServletRequest#getParameterNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames())
- [`ServletRequest#getParameterValues(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String))

Comment: None of the above mentioned methods are not getting called